# Neutral to ground bonding place question

Tags: rcd

Does the neutral-ground bonding need to be done **before** the RCD/GFCI breaker? If there is an energized metal frame due to a fault, will the RCD/GFCI breaker see a difference between live and neutral only if the bonding is done before the breaker?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *Maybe this is a very stupid question but to be sure. Does the
> neutral-ground bonding needs to be done before the RCD/GFCI breaker?*

It absolutely does (as indicated in your diagram).

> *If there is an energized metal frame due to a fault, the RCD/GFCI
> breaker will see a difference between live and neutral only if the
> bonding is done before the breaker?*

Correct.